# Открытие консоли и выполнение команд

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, .net-core

Как открыть окно терминала и выполнить несколько команд в Ubuntu, используя .NET Core?

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Process` работает? Там опцию `UseShellExecute`

Comment: На самом деле я допустил ошибку. Проверил: все работает вполне стандартным методом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для запуска процесса терминала:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "bash";
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.Start();
```

И для получения вывода консоли:

```
Console.WriteLine(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```